# Is it possible to create complex row data based on column data using AWS Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

**Question:**

I have a table structured as follows:

```
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| id | code | size              | count |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA   | TwentyToFortyNine | 65    |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA   | FiveToNinteen     | 385   |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA   | OneToFour         | 492   |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | DK   | OneToFour         | 38    |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | DK   | TwentyToFortyNine | 1     |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | CA   | FiveToNinteen     | 389   |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | CA   | OneToFour         | 494   |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | DK   | FiveToNinteen     | 10    |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | DK   | OneToFour         | 38    |
+----+------+-------------------+-------+
```

The distinct values within the `size` column are: `OneToFour`, `FiveToNinteen`, and `TwentyToFortyNine`. However, not all code entries contain all of these values. For example, the `id: 2` does not have any data for `size: TwentyToFortyNine`.

**Objective:**

I aim to generate new rows for each `id` labeled with `code: TOTAL`, showcasing all the distinct values within the `size` column along with their corresponding total `count`.

Sample output:

```
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| id | code  | size              | count |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | TOTAL | OneToFour         | 530   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | TOTAL | FiveToNinteen     | 385   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | TOTAL | TwentyToFortyNine | 66    |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA    | TwentyToFortyNine | 65    |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA    | FiveToNinteen     | 385   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | CA    | OneToFour         | 492   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | DK    | OneToFour         | 38    |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 1  | DK    | TwentyToFortyNine | 1     |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | TOTAL | OneToFour         | 532   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | TOTAL | FiveToNinteen     | 399   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | TOTAL | TwentyToFortyNine | 0     |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | CA    | FiveToNinteen     | 389   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | CA    | OneToFour         | 494   |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | DK    | FiveToNinteen     | 10    |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 2  | DK    | OneToFour         | 38    |
+----+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to achieve using AWS Athena? If yes, then can you please show how? Or do I need to make use of Pandas for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to figure it out. If someone comes looking for an answer then this might help:

```
WITH all_sizes AS (
    SELECT id, code, size, SUM(count) as total_count
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY id, code, size
),
all_combinations AS (
    SELECT id, 'TOTAL' as code, size, SUM(total_count) as count
    FROM all_sizes
    GROUP BY id, size
    UNION
    SELECT id, code, size, total_count as count
    FROM all_sizes
)
SELECT * FROM all_combinations
ORDER BY id, code, size;
```